# How to get the index number of the selected listview item

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview, listviewitem

I have set these options on my listview

- multiSelect = false
- view = details
- FullRow select = true
- HideSelected  = False.

I have one column which has 10 items. I want to get the selected row index in **vb.net**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim index As Integer = ListView1.SelectedIndices(0)
```

remember indeces in VB.NET are 0-based.

Answer (score 4):

**Try this one:**

```
Dim x as Integer
x = ListView1.FocusedItem.Index
```

**To get the values:**

```
Dim txtValue as String
txtValue = ListView1.FocusedItem.SubItems(0).text
```