# listview condition if selected index

Tags: vb.net

I have a view list with some items

```
movies
music
```

Code:

when I select item 0 it being movies, let me add a new item called `The Matrix Resurrections`.

```
    For I As Integer = 0 To ListView1.Items.Count - 1
        If ListView1.Items(I).Index = 0 Then

            ListView1.Items.Add("The Matrix Resurrections")
        End if
```

unfortunately, it doesn't work like a regular listbox.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847044/how-to-get-the-index-number-of-the-selected-listview-item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ListView` have two option to manage the selection:

- The [SelectedIndices](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.selectedindices?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#System_Windows_Forms_ListView_SelectedIndices) property: gets the indexes of the selected items in the control
- The [SelectedItems](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.selecteditems?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#System_Windows_Forms_ListView_SelectedItems) property: gets the items that are selected in the control

Now, we're talking of *item**s*** and not *item* because, by default, you can select more than one item in yout listbox. If you want to disable the multi-selection, use this code:

```
ListView1.MultiSelect = False
```

Now in your *Sub* (that handles click or selectedIndexChanged event), you can use one of the two properties above. For example:

```
Private Sub ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListView1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If ListView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0 AndAlso ListView1.SelectedIndices(0) = 0 Then
        ListView1.Items.Add("The Matrix Resurrections")
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that using ListView1.SelectedItems

> If no items are currently selected, an empty
> ListView.SelectedIndexCollection is returned

So checking `ListView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0` prevents errors.

**Output**

[image: Output]